RPGLE code does not give an outline in Visual Studio Code
I am trying out VSCode for working with [SQL]RPGLE using the Code for IBM i plugin. It seems like it will work pretty well, except for a pretty major problem I'm seeing.
Whenever I open source code for any RPGLE, it seems to act as if it can't recognize the file despite the linter working. The major issue is that it does not give me an outline view. Instead, it says "No symbols found in document 'ABC.RPGLE'". This is true for both free-format and fixed-format. I have tried running the outline command, but all that seems to do is pull the outline tab up.
This problem doesn't show up for anything else, including CLP, CLLE and SQLRPGLE. They all have the proper outline.
One other symptom I noticed is that a lot of the options when I right-click are missing, which tells me it's deeper than just the outline (although the outline is what I'm really worried about). Here's the right-click menu for both an RPGLE and a SQLRPGLE, respectively:
 
I don't know if this is a bug in the add-on, or if I'm doing something wrong. Google and the Stack search didn't seem to help, and there are no open issues on the add-on's Github repo, so I can only assume it's either brand new or I'm doing something wrong.

I see an older post on the forums about a possible clash with a couple extensions...

nielsliisberg.rpg
RRPG by SpineNetSystems

Additionally, did you install the "IBM i Development Pack" or just Code4i? There's a number of extensions required.  The package has them all, rather than installing one at a time.

If that's not your issue, you may want to post your issue in the Code4i forum.

Okay yeah, I'm not 100% sure which one it was. I created a new profile and only installed Code for IBM i and the IBM i Development Pack. It seems to work fine now. I did not previously have the Development Pack, from what I saw on the docs, it should have worked without it. But c'est la vie. It was probably an extension clash like you said. Thank you!

@Charles is correct. All these RPG extensions are all trying to register their own highlighting for RPG and RPGLE languages - so there is overlap between them. I don't typically recommend having them all.
